# How to lazy load images in Angular from a base64?

Tags: angular

I would load images in my Angular project in lazy way, the issue is that my API returns a base64 image instead of a file.

So i was trying to do something like this:

```
<img class="image-cover" *ngIf="product.image" [src]="'https://localhost:44350/api/images/00168780351/117920?types=products&isThumbnail=true'" loading="lazy"/>
```

But obviously the src is set as link and no image is shown.

What would be the way to perform that? Should i modify my API by returning a file instead?

Comment: what happens, when you write `src="https://localhost:44350/api/images/00168780351/117920?types=products&isThumbnail=true"` instead of `[src]="'https://localhost:44350/api/images/00168780351/117920?types=products&isThumbnail=true'"` ?

Comment: @Argee same result, maybe i should change response type as the API returns text/plain;?

Comment: is the data:image/jpg;base64 prefix in the response?

Comment: Consider answering your question if you feel like it can help somebody with the same problem :) Sounds like your other problem might be better off in a new question though...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The return value of my API was a `text/plain` as `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0...` it wasn't working i src so instead i've changed my API to return `image/jpg`.

To do so i had to change my API as this:

```
[HttpGet("{idProducts}")]
        public FileContentResult GetImages(int idProducts, string idShopsGroup, ImagesTypes types, bool isThumbnail = false)
        {
            string base64Image = ImagesHelper.GetImages(idProducts, idShopsGroup, types, isThumbnail);
            if (base64Image != null)
            {
                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Image);

                return new FileContentResult(bytes, "image/jpg");
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Where instead of returning the plain base64 i've removed `data:image/png;base64,` from it and had to convert it to `bytes` and then return a `FileContentResult`.